# Issues with rules in GitLab CI include

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Given the following pipeline setup:

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
- build

include:
  - local: ci/merge-request.gitlab-ci.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" || ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS)
  - local: ci/default-branch.gitlab-ci.yml
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

merge-request-direct:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "merge-request-direct"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" || ($CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS)
```

`ci/merge-request.gitlab-ci.yml:`

```
merge-request-included:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "merge-request-included"
```

`ci/default-ranch.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
default-branch:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "default-branch"
```

The behaviour is as follows:

- When anything is pushed or merged to the `CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH` branch, only the `default-branch` job is executed as expected.
- When anything is pushed to other branch, no job is executed as expected.
- When merge request is created, only the `merge-request-direct` job is executed which is not as expected. Job `merge-request-included` is expected to run as well, but does not.

When merge request is updated via push to the branch, two pipelines run:

- one for push on a branch which executes both `merge-request-direct` and `merged-request-included` as expected
- one for merge request which executes only `merge-request-direct` which is not as expected. Both jobs mentioned in the previous point should run.

Am I missing something or this is an issue with evaluating conditions?

Comment: I have a similar issue. The conditional include does not seem to work with `if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"`. Did you find a solution or raised a ticket with GitLab?

Comment: The issue has been raised with GitLab support: 
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/393232

Comment: same issue for me..the observation is the last local include only is working